# How do I make ctest run a program with valgrind without dart?

Tags: cmake, valgrind

I want to write a CMakeLists.txt so that I can run my tests normally or with valgrind. I have seen much on integrating ctest with valgrind but all with the assumption that you want to set up a server to submit test results to a dart dashboard. I just want to run the tests on my machine and see the results on the command line.

If I have to do a cmake -D VALGRIND=ON thats fine, but I'd rather generate tests named "foo" and "valgrind_foo" if possible.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I use valgrind for my memory check.  To configure valgrind, I define the following variables in my build system:

```
find_program( MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND valgrind )
set( MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS "--trace-children=yes --leak-check=full" )
```

Also, in there is my valgrind suppression file:

```
set( MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/valgrind_suppress.txt" )
```

After you write your CMakeLists.txt files and configure valgrind correctly in them, you can run the following command:

```
cmake -G ... (to configure your build)
ctest -D ExperimentalBuild (this will build your code)
ctest -R testName -D ExperimentalTest (just runs the test)
ctest -R testName -D ExperimentalMemCheck (to run the test under valgrind)
```

This will trick your build system to run the test automation locally.  It expects you to run:

```
ctest -R testName -D ExperimentalSubmit
```

next, to submit to the (default or your) Dashboard, but you don't need to go through this step to run what you want.  The results will be stored in the Testing/Temporary/ directory.

Answer (score 8):

It seems the following is sufficient.  I wasn't using separate_arguments before, that was my stupidity.

```
function(add_memcheck_test name binary)
  set(memcheck_command "${CMAKE_MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS}")
  separate_arguments(memcheck_command)
  add_test(${name} ${binary} ${ARGN})
  add_test(memcheck_${name} ${memcheck_command} ./${binary} ${ARGN})
endfunction(add_memcheck_test)

function(set_memcheck_test_properties name)
  set_tests_properties(${name} ${ARGN})
  set_tests_properties(memcheck_${name} ${ARGN})
endfunction(set_memcheck_test_properties)
```

Comment: This seems simpler than creating experimental build.

Answer (score 1):

My case was simple enough that I just used a custom target:

```
project(bftest)

add_executable(bftest main.c)

target_link_libraries(bftest LINK_PUBLIC bf)

find_program(VALGRIND "valgrind")
if(VALGRIND)
    add_custom_target(valgrind
        COMMAND "${VALGRIND}" --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20 --track-fds=yes $<TARGET_FILE:bftest>)
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a minimal 'DartConfiguration.tcl' configuration file using `add_custom_target()`. Then you can add a `valgrind` custom target that calls `ctest` with the appropriate args. This is how I usually do it:

```
find_program(VALGRIND "valgrind")
if (VALGRIND)
    set(DART_CONFIG DartConfiguration.tcl)
    add_custom_target(${DART_CONFIG}
        COMMAND echo "MemoryCheckCommand: ${VALGRIND}" >> ${DART_CONFIG}
        COMMENT "Generating ${DART_CONFIG}"
    )
    set(VALGRIND_ARGS
        --leak-check=full
        --error-exitcode=255
    )
    set(LOGFILE memcheck.log)
    add_custom_target(valgrind        
        COMMAND ctest -O ${LOGFILE} -D ExperimentalMemCheck --overwrite MemoryCheckCommandOptions="${VALGRIND_ARGS}"
        COMMAND tail -n1 ${LOGFILE} | grep 'Memory checking results:' > /dev/null
        COMMAND rm -f ${LOGFILE}
        DEPENDS ${DART_CONFIG}
    )
endif()
```

Hope this helps! :-)

Credit: https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/CMakeLists.txt#L237