# How do I add valgrind tests to my cmake "test" target

Tags: c++, cmake, valgrind

I run unit tests by building with `ninja` and then running `ninja test` from my build tree:

```
cmake -G Ninja /source/tree
ninja
ninja test
```

However, to run valgrind I need to run it manually:

```
valgrind rel/path/to/test
```

I'd like `valgrind` to run automatically when I run `ninja test`. [According to the cmake documentation](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/ctest/Testing-With-CTest) *"setting up [valgrind tests] is **extremely easy**"*, but when I run

```
ctest -D NightlyMemoryCheck
```

I just get this error:

```
Cannot find file: /home/arman/tinman/deb/DartConfiguration.tcl
   Site: 
   Build name: (empty)
WARNING: No nightly start time found please set in CTestConfig.cmake or DartConfig.cmake
Problem initializing the dashboard.
```

I get a similar error when I follow the instructions from this SO question:

[How do I make ctest run a program with valgrind without dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303711/how-do-i-make-ctest-run-a-program-with-valgrind-without-dart)

I don't know what `dart` is, but according the website it's some kind of online testing doodad.

Clearly *extremely easy* is not easy enough for me. Does anyone know of a solution that is so supremely easy that you'd have to be some kind of IT warlock to make it *not* work?

Comment: I think you need to use the `ctest_memcheck` command, cf. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/ctest_memcheck.html#command:ctest_memcheck and https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/ctest.1.html?highlight=valgrind#ctest-memcheck-step

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Here is a self contained example that shows how to add valgrind tests to a CMake project. The example consists of a single C++ source file `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double* leak = new double[10];
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
}
```

The code contains an intentional leak which should be picked up by valgrind. We also need a `CMakeLists.txt` file which requires CMake >= 2.8:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project (ValgrindExample)

include (CTest)
add_executable(example main.cpp)
add_test(example_test example)
```

Here it is important to include the CTest module with `include` instead of just enabling tests with `enable_testing()`. The CTest module takes care of setting up the machinery for being able to run memory checks with tests (e.g., it locates the valgrind executable).

Now we can open a shell session in the project folder and create a Ninja build tree:

```
$ mkdir build; cd build
$ cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

We can build and run tests *without* valgrind in the regular way:

```
$ ninja
[2/2] Linking CXX executable example
$ ninja test
[0/1] Running tests...
...
100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.01 sec
```

To run tests *with* valgrind we have to use CMake's ctest executable with the test action `memcheck`:

```
$ ctest -T memcheck
...
1/1 MemCheck #1: example_test .....................   Passed    0.77 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.77 sec
-- Processing memory checking output: 
Memory checking results:
Memory Leak - 2
```

ctest prints a summary of the memory checking results. The detailed output of valgrind is located in a temporary directory in the build tree:

```
$ cat ./Testing/Temporary/MemoryChecker.*.log
==4565== 80 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 37 of 64
==4565==    at 0x10000B681: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.12.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==4565==    by 0x1000507DD: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==4565==    by 0x100000F93: main (main.cpp:5)
...
```

It is not possible to automatically run valgrind when you run `ninja test` because CMake's built-in test target cannot be modified and always runs tests in the regular way. We can however add a custom CMake target which invokes ctest with the `-T memcheck` option and then prints the detailed valgrind report:

```
add_custom_target(test_memcheck
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} 
        --force-new-ctest-process --test-action memcheck
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E cat "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Testing/Temporary/MemoryChecker.*.log"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
```

`--test-action` is the verbose version of the switch `-T`.

We then can invoke valgrind testing from Ninja with

```
$ ninja test_memcheck
```

and get the results as if we ran valgrind manually.

Comment: So there is a default command used in this example with test-action memcheck. If I were to want to specify a custom suppressions file, or using custom parameters all together to pass to valgrind(such as running a full leak check), how would one go about doing so?

Comment: Set the variable `CTEST_MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE`. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CTEST_MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE.html

Comment: How to cat valgrind log only when valgrind check failed? How to exit with -1?

Comment: @sakra How do you set the `CTEST_MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE` variable? I tried to use the `-D` option to ctest, but that doesn't seem to do anything. Any ideas? I really want to be able to set the suppressions file and the memcheck options from the command line when running ctest.

Comment: The custom target is missing `WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"`.

Comment: @dcmm88 I got this working by using `MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE` instead.