# Passing valgrind flags from cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, valgrind, ctest

Complementary to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325957/how-do-i-add-valgrind-tests-to-my-cmake-test-target), how can I pass *flags* to [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) from cmake?

```
# enable valgrind checks
set(CTEST_MEMORYCHECK_TYPE "valgrind")
set(CTEST_MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS "--leak-check=no")
```

According to [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CTEST_MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS.html), The lines above *should* work, but after running `cmake .` + `make` I get:

```
$ ctest -T memcheck | grep "Memory Leak\|Defects"
1/1 MemCheck: #1: test .............................   Defects: 1
Memory Leak - 1
```

When I inspect the `DartConfiguration.tcl` file I *don't see my flag* there:

```
$ sed -n "79,80p" ./DartConfiguration.tcl 
MemoryCheckCommand: /usr/local/bin/valgrind
MemoryCheckCommandOptions: # <--- nothing here ...
```

After *manually* editing `DartConfiguration.tcl` everything *works fine*:

```
$ sed -i "s/MemoryCheckCommandOptions:/MemoryCheckCommandOptions: --leak-check=no/g" DartConfiguration.tcl
$ ctest -T memcheck | grep "Memory Leak\|Defects"
$ # nothing ( good )
```

- All the details exist in the public repo: https://github.com/OrenGitHub/ValgrindCmake
- Particularly, the cmake test pipelines: [here](https://github.com/OrenGitHub/ValgrindCmake/actions/runs/3399973292/jobs/5654074665#step:7:16) and [here](https://github.com/OrenGitHub/ValgrindCmake/actions/runs/3399984380/jobs/5654094011#step:8:12)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60741757/4074081)?

Comment: @dewaffled no, it doesn't work

Comment: I ended up [calling valgrind directly](https://github.com/OrenGitHub/ValgrindCmake/actions/runs/3400653025/jobs/5655222450#step:7:2). When leaks are *not* ignored, [the pipeline breaks](https://github.com/OrenGitHub/ValgrindCmake/actions/runs/3400646191/jobs/5655211581#step:7:2) (like it should)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...wrong include order and variable name.
Try this!

```
set(MEMORYCHECK_TYPE "valgrind")
set(MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS "--leak-check=no")
include(CTest)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).